# Google calendar, showing only one event for events happening on the same time

Tags: google-calendar-api

**Context**
I wrote a python script, that uses boto3, that can stop or start entire development environments on AWS. This all works fine. 
I thought it would be a neat feature to hook it up to a google calendar, to check which environments are booked, and should therefore be switched on.

I created a google calendar, and added two "events" for the same timeframe, over the same period of time. Example:

1. Integration environment **A** should be on each day, for the next month, starting at 09h00, and ending at 17h00
2. Integration environment **B** should be on each day, for the next month, starting at 09h00, and ending at 17h00

**Problem**
I am using the google API and python, but the problem is, that I only ever get back one of the events. For example, I am only getting back Integration environment **A** when I should be getting back Integration environment **B** also.

I'm not sure why this is, but I would really appreciate it if you could point me in the right direction

[image: Google Calendar view]
[image: Public Calendar View]

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

I mistakenly booked the one event under my own calendar. Booking it under the right calendar, fixed the issue.